# Bare Git repo cannot add files or commit files

Tags: linux, git, permissions, centos

So I have been plagued with this weird git problem that myself and a few other developers have not been able to solve. Here it is:

I created a bare repo for managing website changes using git on test server. 
For this example the repo is here: /home/website/website.git
The website public root would be here: /home/website

I created the repo by doing this command: git init --bare
inside the git repo directory "website.git"

Next I have my local repo on a machine elsewhere. This is a standard git repo. I build the site get it ready to deploy. When its ready I push it to the bare repo. From my local repo. 
There is a post-receive hook that checks the latest file tree out into the public root of the website. So when I change things on the local repo and test them in the localhost environment, once satisfied I can push them to the live server.

Here is the problem I face:
I can push fine. No issues. All works as expected. Code gets checked out to public root. Everybody is happy and goes on with their life.

BUT!!!:
The site is a CMS site. Users log in to it and upload things. Files get created on the public root of the website which is the GIT_WORK_TREE.

So NBD right?! I can just commit the files every now and then from the live bare repo and pull them back to my local environment like I have before. So I log into SSH on the server. Navigate to /home/website/website.git
Then run this command: 
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/website/ git add ../

I get this mess:

```
error: unable to create temporary sha1 filename ./objects/cb: No such file or directory
error: error_log: failed to insert into database
error: unable to index file error_log
fatal: adding files failed
```

I have done this before on other servers and it worked fine from what I remember. So I was like WTF, must be something strange on this server. I went to another server I have and replicated the EXACT same steps. Got the EXACT same problem. So now I fear I am loosing my sanity and maybe these previous git experiences are all made up in my head.... *Well, lets not go that far yet.... :)

Maybe somebody can help me out here. I have used git plenty and can't seem to crack this one.

Oh, some other maybe useful specs:
running CENTOS 6.2

I double checked all permissions. I even tried changing everything to 777 recursively just to make sure Im not loosing it somehow. Made sure all the files are owned by the correct user. chowned recursively. I also tried the standard solution to this problem which is described here: https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/132671/git-commit-fails-with-sourcetree-error-unable-to-create-temporary-sha1-filename-git-objects-d8-file-exists
That didnt work either. Not sure where to go from here.

PLEASE HELP ME!!!!
I feel like Linus is playing cruel tricks on me right now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution. This is it. I was running the above command from the git repo.

Turns out the command should be run from the work tree and altered to look like this:

```
GIT_WORK_TREE=/home/website/  git --git-dir="./website.git/"  add ./
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a bare git repository in /home/website/website.git which is inside of a git repository in /home/website?  And then you try to trick the bare git repository into having a working tree using `GIT_WORK_TREE`?

Maybe it is worth understanding this setup but only if you intend to be a `git` developer.  As you are a user focused on delivering website functionality, I suggest using a standard `git` setup.

Move the bare git repository elsewhere:

```
$ mkdir /home/repo
$ mv /home/website/website.git /home/repo/website.git
$ cd /home/website
$ git remote set-url origin /home/repo/website.git
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I will try to implement this solution tomorrow morning. Do you have any idea about why the permissions problems?

Comment: @GoZoner I think you're missing a step or two, and the url for `set-url` is wrong.  Since `/home/website` is not really a git repo, he probably needs to set that up with a `git init` prior to the last step.  And the url should be `/home/repo/website.git`, no?  He probably needs to fetch and sync the master branch to the current master of the repo.

Comment: Thanks.  /home/website is already a .git repository.  I fixed the `set-url` target.